# Cargar mensaje dependiendo si inicia o cierra sesión

Tags: angularjs, ionic

Cargo un mensaje el cual depende de si el usuario ingresa o cierra sesión, pero existe el problema, de que solo me muestra el mensaje de inicio de sesion en ambos casos. Uso el método `backView()`, el cual siempre obtiene la vista anterior a la que se esta estacionada. A continuación el código:

#### loading.js

```
angular.module('loadingPage', ['ionic', 'loginApp', 'historialApp'])
    .controller('mostrarMensaje', mostrarMensaje)
    .factory('obtenerVista', obtenerVista);

mostrarMensaje.$inject = ['$scope', 'obtenerVista'];

function mostrarMensaje($scope, obtenerVista) {

    var vista_Anterior, valor_sesion;

    vista_Anterior = obtenerVista.nombreVista();

    if (vista_Anterior.stateName === "login") {
        $scope.mensaje = "Cargando Informacion";
    } else {
        $scope.mensaje = "Cerrando sesion";
    }

}


obtenerVista.$inject = ['$ionicHistory'];

function obtenerVista($ionicHistory) {

    return {

        nombreVista: function() {

            var vista;
            vista = $ionicHistory.backView();
            return vista;

        }

    };

}
```

Aquí un dibujo para ser mas especifico, si algo nos e entiende

[image: mensaje de inicio/cierre]

Gracias de antemano por al ayuda.

Comment: Puedes poner un `console.log(vista_Anterior.stateName);` para ver que salida tiene en cada caso?

Comment: Bueno ya se que intentas, si estoy en el template loading, la vista anterior es login, y si estoy en el menu, la vista anterior es loading.

Comment: Eso basado en los console.log, cierto..los console.log son para ver si de verdad esta llegando a esos valores...claramente la condicion del if no esta funcionando, por eso quiero ver que valor toma la variable cuando te logueas y el valor que toma cuando cieras session

Comment: Pues de momento no puedo mostrarte el console.log, ya que no tengo mi computador conmigo, pero el problema de usar `backView`, es que el siempre me va mostrar la vista anterior, en este caso, la vista del login, entonces, no sirve ese metodo por eso lo deseche, estoy usando el de la respuesta de abajo pero tampoco, que me recomiendas?

Comment: La forma de abordar el problema esta bien.....pero la condicion del if esta invertida...dibiese ser: `if ($window.localStorage.logged)` en vez de `if (!$window.localStorage.logged)`...ahora podrias anadir tus metodos de login y logout en la pregunta?

Comment: @Hackerman dame un momento que noe stoy en la casa voy a ver si lo consigo por aqui,o me lo pasa alguien, y ya he hecho eso, y la primera vez que ingreso, solo muestra el primer mensaje, deboe entrar una vez mas sin salir de la app para que tal cosa suceda

Comment: No hay problema...yo igual me voy a mi casa en estos momentos...feliz Viernes :v

Comment: listo, igual modifico la pregunta y te aviso, puedes responder mas tarde?

Comment: aqui esta esta imagen usando el metodo de la respuesta, http://imgur.com/a/mGQIw

Comment: ¿Dónde se inicializa la variable stateName?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro es un atributo que viene en el objeto que recibo del factory, deja que llegue a la casa y te muestro que es, y por que no suo ese metodo ahora

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bueno pude resolver el problema de la siguiente manera:

Lo que ocurría, era que loading.js varificaba lo que estaba en `window.localStorage.logged` una sola vez, por eso debía ingresar múltiples veces para que ocurriera

Así que para resolverlo, hice uso de los ciclos de vida de las vistas, en este caso utilice el evento `$ionicView.beforeEnter`. lo activa al entrar en la página ( carga desde la caché o creado por primera vez ).

```
$scope.$on('$ionicView.beforeEnter', function () {
  if (!$window.localStorage.logged) {
      $scope.mensaje = "Loading Information";
  } else {
      $scope.mensaje = "Closing Session";
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Yo utilizo otro sistema que igual te resulta más sencillo. Se trata de guardar un valor en localStorage para saber si está o no está el usuario logueado.

Basta con añadir en la función de login:

```
$window.localStorage.logged = true;
```

y en la función de logout:

```
delete $window.localStorage.logged;
```

Así a la hora de mostrar el mensaje:

```
function mostrarMensaje($scope, $window) {

    if (!$window.localStorage.logged) {
        $scope.mensaje = "Cargando Información";
    } else {
        $scope.mensaje = "Cerrando sesión";
    }
}
```

Comment: gracias voy a probar, por que he estado probando varias cosas, y me funciona pero solo después que ingresa la primera vez, por que en la primera vez sale el mismo mensaje para ambos, Supongo que cuando cierre sesión debo hacer esto `$window.localStorage.logged = false;`

Comment: Sí, puedes ponerlo a false o directamente borrar la variable, ambas (false o undefined) cumplirán el if y entrarán, si la variable existe y tiene cualquier valor (distinto de 0) no cumplirá el if y saltará al else.

También es recomendable que pongas a false o borres la variable una vez hayas llamado a la función para que no crea que es la primera vez que entra.

Comment: Pues lo probé y ahora solo sale **Cerrando sesión**, voy a probar esto ultimo que pones aqui

Comment: Este código no funciona en lo absoluto. En localStorage el metodo para agregar y borrar claves es con `setItem`, `getItem` y `removeItem`.

Comment: @devconcept la API de localStorage permite trabajar de ambas formas. Así que es indistintinto escribir `$window.localStorage.logged`, `$window.localStorage['logged']` o `$window.localStorage.getItem('logged')`. Fuente: [MDN: Using the Web Storage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API)

Comment: Cierto!!! Corregida la votación. Saludos